# C# - Compute total hours between 8:00 to 2:00 AND 8:00 to 12:00

Tags: c#

Here's my code

```
DateTime TimeIn = "8:00 AM",
         TimeOut="2:00 AM";
double Total;

private void compute()
{
    Total = (TimeOut - TimeIn).TotalHours;
}
```

`8:00am to 2:00am` should result `18 hours`.But mine is resulting `-7`
Another problem is when i typed `24:00` as time out C# couldn't recognize it as Time.

It works properly when the `TimeOout` is less than `12:00am`. like `11:59pm` backwards.
`(eg.: 11:30PM - 8:00AM)` it computes properly.

Please Help.

Comment: This will works only if the timeIn and timeOut are on the same day. You have to include the date part as well for this expected result

Comment: From 8 AM to 2 AM there is only 7 hours difference. So the answer you got is correct. Your problem is different. You don't have date included with time. To make it more clear... what will be the total hours when timein is 8 AM and timeout is 8 AM ? Will it be zero or 24. So, date part is required. Anyway this trick may help you .. If TimeOut < TimeIn then you can add 24 hours to timeout and then try subtraction.

Comment: @un-lucky how can I include date part for my expected result. Could you give some simple example. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NikkoSunglao in c# how can you use this declaration `DateTime TimeIn = "8:00 AM",
TimeOut="2:00 AM";`

Comment: @MukulVarshney I got your point. Can you five some sample on the process you said. Thank you

Comment: @MeerDeen that's not what i really declare. this is just shortcut. DateTime TimeIn = Convert.ToDateTime("8:00AM");

Comment: @NikkoSunglao you should write code in more clear way so that the users here can help you

Comment: @MeerDeen Sorry. I will edit my codes.

Comment: How should the computer know that 2:00AM is 2 hours after midnight from the next day? It can be 2 hours after midnight from Thursday next week as well, or from Friday last week.

Comment: @MukulVarshney thankyou for your comment. i really appreciate it. now i can continue coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add +24 hours when negative result.

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help you:

```
string TimeIn= "8:00 AM";
string TimeOut= "2:00 AM";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(TimeOut).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(TimeIn));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have declared the datetime Value is wrong. The right way to do it is by converting the string to datetime format

```
DateTime TimeIn = Convert.ToDateTime("08:00");
DateTime TimeOut = Convert.ToDateTime("02:00");
TimeSpan ts = TimeIn - TimeOut;
```

If you need the 18 hours span that you're looking for you'll have to pass the date value as well while assigning data to the variables

Comment: No for that you will have to pass the date value as well @SirRufo

Comment: Yes. I just shortcut my code. I declare DateTime just like yours. Thank you

Comment: @NikkoSunglao there's nothing known as 24:00 hours you have to use the next date with 00:00 as the time

Comment: @NikkoSunglao And rather than using double you should use timespan that will give you positive value by default